# how to map 1V - 10V to 1.6V to 3.2V for voltage regulation using TL494

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-electronics, voltage-divider, tl494, constant-voltage

I am trying to design the given circuit where pin 1 is the non inverting terminal of comparator where I want to use a ref voltage of 1V - 10V but IC TL494 is accepting a voltage of 1.6V to 3.2V....and pin 2 m trying to give an o/p voltage feedback which varies from 10V - 100V through resistor divider circuit.. So how could i can map (1- 10V) to (1.6 to 3.2)V through resistor divider circuit..[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you're mapping one voltage range to another there's a scaling factor and an offset.
Take the range of the voltages you're converting from, you've stated two different ranges, 10-100 and 1-10, we'll use the former.

100 - 10 = 90

And the range you're converting to

3.2 - 1.6 = 1.6

to scale 90 to 1.6 you would divide:

90 / 1.6 = 56.25

That's the division ratio you need. Now you need the offset.

Take the low value you're converting from, divide by the scaling factor, and the see how much off that is from the low value you're converting to:

10 / 56.25 = 0.1777...
1.6 - 0.1777... = 1.4222...

So you need to add 1.4222... V to whatever you get out of your divider.
Let's check that with 100 V.

100 / 56.25 = 1.777...
1.777... + 1.4222... = 3.2

So you need to divide by 56.25, and add 1.4222..., the division can be done with a voltage divider, the addition can be done with an opamp.

Comment: You were faster. :-)